# Laravel match multiple search words

Tags: php, laravel, search, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to modify a template that uses Laravel and I am very new to this language. I am trying to filter search results to match ALL searched terms.

For example, user searches for "Red", search returns all red results. User searches for "Trucks", search returns all trucks. But if a user searches for "Red Trucks", search returns both "red" search results and "trucks" search results. So red cars and red bikes are there, as well as yellow trucks etc... But I only want "Red Trucks" to be shown. If a result doesn't have one of the tags saved with it, I don't want it shown. Currently it just has to contain one of the tags and it's shown.

I know I need to modify the "where" and "orwhere" parts for the 'tags' and probably change them to '=', but I can't get it to work through my trial and error.

For reference, an uploaded photo of a red truck would have the following in the tag field in phpmyadmin: red,lowered,s10,truck,gloss,custom,stripes

So searching for "Red Truck"should return this image, and not include any "red" "cars".

The search text box has a name="q" and id="srch-term" . A search for "Red Truck" would show /search?q=red+truck in the browser.

Base Code:

```
public function search($search, $timeframe = null)
{
    $extends = explode(' ', $search);
    $images = $this->posts($timeframe)->Where('tags', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
        ->whereNull('deleted_at')->whereNotNull('approved_at')->orderBy('approved_at', 'desc');

    foreach ($extends as $extend) {
            $images->orWhere('tags', 'LIKE', '%' . $extend . '%')->whereNotNull('approved_at')->whereNull('deleted_at');
    }

    return $images = $images->with('user', 'comments', 'favorites')->whereNotNull('approved_at')->whereNull('deleted_at')->paginate(perPage());
}
```

Comment: Did you try to replace `orwhere` by `where` clause, what do you get as result

Comment: Single term search works, but multiple word search returns 0 results.

Comment: Answer Updated. Try that way

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out!

```
Public function search($search, $timeframe = null)
{
$extends = explode(' ', $search);
$images = $this->posts($timeframe)
             ->whereNull('deleted_at')->whereNotNull('approved_at') 
             ->orderBy('approved_at', 'desc');

$images->where(function($q) use ($extends) {
   foreach ($extends as $extend) {
       $q->Where('tags', 'LIKE', '%' . $extend . '%');
   }
});

return $images->with('user', 'comments', 'favorites')->paginate(perPage());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going good. Just need to use [whereIn](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#where-clauses) in your query like this.

```
$images->whereCategoryId($categoryId)->whereIn('tags', $extends)->whereNotNull('approved_at')->whereNull('deleted_at');
```

**UPDATED ANSWER**

```
public function search($search, $category = null, $timeframe = null)
{
    if ($category)
        $categoryId = $this->category->whereSlug($category)->first();

    $images = $this->posts($category, $timeframe)->with('user', 'comments', 'favorites')->whereNotNull('approved_at')->whereNull('deleted_at');

    if (isset($categoryId))
        $images->whereCategoryId($categoryId);

    $images->whereIn('tags', explode(' ', $search));

    return $images->orderBy('approved_at', 'desc')->paginate(perPage());
}
```

Comment: Now all searches come back blank/empty. I've adjusted my initial snippet of code to remove the category mentions since I want to search across all categories anyways.'